# Custom background color per item?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, fltk

I have a `Fl_Choice` with few options, for example:

```
Fl_Choice* o = new Fl_Choice(70, 100, 240, 25, "Some Options:");
o->add("Blue");
o->add("Black");
o->add("Orange");
o->add("Purple");
```

I did like to set a custom color for the background of each item while leaving the foreground color to white.

**How do I set a custom background per item?**

NOTE: I am using v90, not sure what tag I should use for that one or if vs2008 is sufficient, kindly remove this note if its sufficient as is or drop me a comment with what other tag I should add.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to set the background colour but you can set the foreground colour

```
Fl_Menu_Item choices[] =
{
    //                                               ,-- The colour
    {"red",0,(Fl_Callback*)0, (void*) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF000000},
    {"blue",0,(Fl_Callback*)0, (void*) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0000FF00},
    {"green",0,(Fl_Callback*)0, (void*) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x00FF0000},
    {"yellow",0,(Fl_Callback*)0, (void*) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFFFF0000},
    {0}
};

...

Fl_Choice *c = new Fl_Choice(50,250,200,25);
c->menu(choices);
```

Alternatively, you can derive from Fl_Choice if you don't want so many zeros

```
class ColourChoice: public Fl_Choice
{
public:
   ColourChoice(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char* l = 0)
      : Fl_Choice(x, y, w, h, l)
   {
   }

   void add(const char* text, Fl_Color color)
   {
       Fl_Choice::add(text);
       Fl_Menu_Item* item = const_cast<Fl_Menu_Item*>(find_item(text));
       item->labelcolor(color);
   }
};

...
ColourChoice* c = new ColourChoice(...);
c->add("purple", (Fl_Color)0xFF00FF00);
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, how different it is for the background? I don't even know what to look for honestly... fltk is a great lib, but this minor things are really hard to find examples or anything. Unhappily I can't up vote your answer but hopefully a good soul will do so in my place until I can do it myself.

Comment: No need to upvote - just tick it as the answer.  Changing the background involves rewriting Fl_Menu with a colour option for the background.  Takes a while to understand the FLTK code: there are lots of one-liners and single letter variables.  The main problem with background is you may also have to change the foreground colour since some combinations are not very legible - eg black on blue.  Another option would be to use Fl_Radio_Light_Button and change the colours of the lights but that would take up more space than Fl_Choice.

Comment: but would it still be a dropdown selection? could you perhaps show me an example of that?

Comment: Have a look at the first option - there is already an example there.  Just define the Fl_Menu_Item array and set the list using your Fl_Choice variable menu.  Just try it and see what you get.

Comment: well for a start there is no Fl_Radio_Light_Button neither in fluid or in the lib, maybe you're using a different lib or have custom classes or at least I was unable to find it with 1.3.3... But given I would have to replace the Fl_Choice for, say Fl_Radio, it wouldn't be a dropdown anymore is what I meant. Nevertheless thanks for the efforts, it doesn't actually answer the question, but does show how to change the foreground color of a label.